# server connection failed while connecting loopback with firebase

Tags: firebase, loopback

facing problem while connection loopback with firebase using loopback-connector-firebase.am using loopbacksdk builder.it shows an error "Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined". am including my server side code files here.

datasource.json

```
{
"db": {
"name": "db",
"connector": "memory"
},
"angular2seedadvanced": {
"host": "host name",
"name": "angular2seedadvanced",
"connector": {
  "firebase": {
        "url": "<firebase_url>",
        "token": "<security_token>"
    }
},
"index": "angular2seedadvanced"
}
}
```

how can i solve this issue?